# How to check if a number in a list is a perfect square?

Tags: python, square

I have to check if in a list numbers are perfect squares ( with true or false), but it doesn't return me anything.

What did I get wrong? I'm new in python so sorry

Answer (score 2):

- Have you called the function yet?
- Don't use `list` as a name of the variable
- Update the function to return `True` only when all elements have a perfect square.

code:

```
num_list = [4, 9, 16]

def check_is_quadratic(x):
    result = []
    for i in x:
       if math.sqrt(i).is_integer():
           result.append(True)
       else: 
           result.append(False)
    return all(result)

print(check_is_quadratic(num_list))
```

output:

> ```
> > print(check_is_quadratic([4, 9, 16]))
> True
> > print(check_is_quadratic([4, 8, 16]))
> False
> ```

---

UPDATE

code with list comprehension:

```
num_list = [4, 8, 16]
result = [math.sqrt(num).is_integer() for num in num_list]
print(result)
print(all(result))
```

output:

```
> [True, False, True]
> False
```

Comment: but if I change a number ( for ex 4, 8, 16) it gives me true , but 8 it's not a perfect square –

Comment: @SARA, I've updated it, please see. Now, it requires all elements with perfect square to return `True`.

Comment: If you need to return them one by one, you just return `result` e.g. `[4, 8, 16]` --> `[True, False, True]`.

Comment: thank you, is it possible use comprehesion list?

Comment: Yes it is, see in my updated answer @SARA.

Comment: List comprehension can be shortened to `[math.sqrt(num).is_integer() for num in num_list]` [the letter l is often indistinguishable from 1] `is_integer()` returns boolean, why even check for it?

Answer (score 1):

You are:

1. Not calling your function or printing anything
2. Using the global variable `list` inside your fucntion instead of the passed value
3. Using the reserved word `list` as a variable name, which is bad practice
4. Using return statement inside the if-else block here will give you only True/False once. What you want is to return True/False for each element inside your `testList`

An updated code could look like this:

```
import math

test_list = [4, 10, 16]

    
def check_is_quadratic(list_in_function):

    for i in list_in_function:
       if not math.sqrt(i).is_integer(): 
           return False # If one is not perfect square, then we can say False
    return True # Only after the complete for-loop we can say that all values are perfect squares

print(check_is_quadratic(test_list))
```

Comment: Semantically, it still has the problem of returning prematurely.

Comment: Yes, consider using the built-in `all` function

Comment: but if I change a number  ( for ex 4, 8, 16) it gives me true , but 8 it's not a perfect square

Comment: Specifically `return all([math.sqrt(i).is_integer() for i in list_in_function])` [CamelCase Notation is not pythonic]

Comment: @SARA I have updated the answer to first show how to get the code running that you had and then show you what needs to be done to get the functionality working properly

Comment: are you sure that "       if not math.sqrt(i)result.is_integerappend():  " is correct?

Comment: More concise way : 
print(list(map(lambda x: math.sqrt(x).is_integer(), input_list) ))

Comment: it gives me error

Comment: @Raumschifffan CamelCase notation is pythonic, and a person can use it, it's in [python code style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: downvoting solution because it is throwing error

Comment: @sahasrara62 Please read your sources. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Comment: @SARA sorry for that, it is fixed now

Comment: @Raumschifffan you are correct about PEP8